# forecasting tensorflow confused with usage of repeat

Tags: python, tensorflow, forecasting

I came across this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SGsU5jyuJVodUwAhf3Budeyh7c-gHXOR?usp=sharing#scrollTo=daUW6l6wO0RA) that covers forecasting. I got it through this [article](https://analyticsindiamag.com/how-to-do-multivariate-time-series-forecasting-using-lstm/).

I am confused about the 2nd and 4th line from below

```
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
train_data = train_data.cache().shuffle(buffer_size).batch(batch_size).repeat()

val_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_vali, y_vali))
val_data = val_data.batch(batch_size).repeat()
```

I understand that we are trying to shuffle our data as we dont want to feed data to our model in the serial order. On additional reading I realized that it is better to have `buffer_size` same as the size of the dataset. But I am not sure what `repeat` is doing in this case. Could someone explain what is being done here and what is the function of `repeat`?

I also looked at this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53514495/what-does-batch-repeat-and-shuffle-do-with-tensorflow-dataset) and saw below text but still not clear.

```
The following methods in tf.Dataset :

repeat( count=0 ) The method repeats the dataset count number of times.
shuffle( buffer_size, seed=None, reshuffle_each_iteration=None) The method shuffles the samples in the dataset. The buffer_size is the number of samples which are randomized and returned as tf.Dataset.
batch(batch_size,drop_remainder=False) Creates batches of the dataset with batch size given as batch_size which is also the length of the batches.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repeat call with nothing passed to the count param makes this dataset repeat infinitely.

In python terms, Datasets are a subclass of python iterables. If you have an object `ds` of type `tf.data.Dataset`, then you can execute `iter(ds)`. If the dataset was generated by `repeat()`, then it will never run out of items, i.e., it will never throw a `StopIteration` exception.

In the notebook you referenced, the call to tf.keras.Model.fit() is passed an argument of `100` to the param `steps_per_epoch`. This means that the dataset should be infinitely repeating, and Keras will pause training to run validation every 100 steps.

tldr: leave it in.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3f878cff5b698b82eea85db2b60d65a2e320850e/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py#L134-L3445

https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html

Comment: in case of this specific example, is it safe to delete `repeat` part then? it is necessary ?

Comment: It depends on your training loop. If your training loop is expecting an infinite dataset, then you need to keep the repeat. Usually, people train with a number of epochs where an epoch is a full sweep of the dataset, so in that case you would remove the repeat.

Comment: thanks, I am running for 10 epochs and will remove `repeat` part. do you agree with it is better to have `buffer_size` same as the size of the dataset? any thoughts on what should be my `buffer_size`?

Comment: You want a buffer size as big as physically possible to get the best shuffle. If you are using TFRecords as the underlying disk storage, it is a Google technology called RecordIO which was designed for spinning magnetic platter disks. With SSD disks, the whole TFRecord -> tf.data.Dataset should be revamped, but it's too ingrained into the API. I'm working on a loader that will shuffle via random access to a TFRecord, rather than serially loading it and performing a weak shuffle. Determined released YogaDL in the same vein.