# How does tensorflow Dataset.repeat(count=None) work?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In the documentation it says if you run repeat(), the default behavior (if count is None or -1) is for the dataset be repeated indefinitely (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#repeat). But what is indefinitely exactly?

I read somewhere that, for the code below, "defaule is repeated till number of time batch run", but I don't understand what that means or if it is even correct.

```
train_univariate.cache().shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE).repeat()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does batch, repeat, and shuffle do with TensorFlow Dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53514495/what-does-batch-repeat-and-shuffle-do-with-tensorflow-dataset)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not really, my question is related to the absence of an argument in the method Dataset.repeat(), i.e. when count=None. I don't understand what, in practical terms, is indefinitely.